# Python 2.7 + Raspberry Pi 3 + UART (Serial)

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial, uart, raspberry-pi3

some trouble with Python on RPi3 over UART. 
My Python 2.7 script:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)

while 1:
    ser.write('hello')
    time.sleep(1)
```

And output in terminal is:

```
hellohello`??p?nnn?`??p?nnn?`??p?nnn?`??p?nnn?`??p?nnn?`??p?nnn?`??p?nnn?
```

Sometimes is "hello" two times, sometimes five times. 
Standars RPi3 console output is off (in raspi-config). UART converter is 3V3 logic.

Could you help me? Thanx a lot!

Waldi

Comment: I'm not really sure, but the timeout value you give in the constructor of Serial is a read timeout. If you do not send a text to the raspi for 1 second the connection is reset. It seams that only the configuration is reset, that's strange. Please, could you try out your script with `timeout=0`?

Comment: Hello Peter, I tried timeout=0, but outpus is same. I tried another two converters and without possitive effect. Thanks for any idea.

Comment: On Raspi 3 the UART 0 Port is used for Bluetooth you have to use the Port 1 which is mapped to the Pins 14 and 15. That could be the reason.

Comment: I know that port 0 is for BL and I'm using port 1 on pins 14 and 15. It's not working.                                                                                I tried the same code on RPi1 and it's working fine.                                         Now I found help on: https://frillip.com/raspberry-pi-3-uart-baud-rate-workaround/          and      http://www.briandorey.com/post/Raspberry-Pi-3-UART-Overlay-Workaround           and is working fine on RPi3.

Comment: Sorry, I was interrupted before I could review my last comment. You're right. I forgott to mention that the baud rate of UART1  is bound to the core frequency. But as it seams you got it by yourself. ;-) Could you please answer you question with your solution and mark it as the acepted answer. Then it could be found easier.